# Identifying if a condition is met based on a dynamic range in another column

Tags: r

I have a column with a lot of zero values and the occasional decimal value, e.g.

```
c <- c(0,0,0,0.0927,0,0,0.100821,0)
```

I have a separate column, `v`, which has all decimal numbers in it:

```
v <- c(0.091,0.0981,0.101,0.102,0.092,0.1,0.091,0.099)
```

Where I have a value >0 in `c`, I want to look in column `v` *from that observation forward* (i.e. from that row downwards) to see if, anywhere in that range, there is a value that is lower than the specific value in that row / observation of `c`. Ideally I'd like to return the value and / or the row number / index of the first occurring instance of a lower number.

The output would look like this: 
(NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 8, NA)

I.e. the output returns the row number in v of the next instance in v which is lower than the corresponding number in C. It ignores the first value in v, .091, even though it's lower than the first number in C (.0927) because it happened before (the data is chronological) the occurrence in C. I only want to look in subsequent rows.

I really, really appreciate any help. :-)
W

Comment: Why are you overwriting `c` in your declaration of `v`?

Comment: Does "from that row downwards" include the row itself?

Comment: It would be better to start from the subsequent row if possible. However I don't think it would break the code if I started on the same row.

Comment: Maurits - My apologies. That was a copy/paste error. I have now corrected it. I did not mean to overwrite c!!

Comment: I think I understand, but I'm not sure. Could you share an even simpler example with, say, 6 values and include the expected output?

Comment: Also, in R we usually avoid using `c` as a variable name since it's already the name of the most common function.

Comment: Gregor - I edited the question as per your comments. Thank you, it's clearer now, I think.    That's not really my variable name, BTW. I just picked 'c' for 'column' (of data!) to illustrate the question. But it's a fair point and I'll use x,y or z next time!

Comment: I'm thinking that the answer is probably a for ... loop. It just seems that they can almost always be avoided.....

Comment: I don't understand you're logic! Shouldn't your expected outcome be `(NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 6, NA)`? Because for `c[7] = 0.100821`, you have `v[6] = 0.1` which is closer to (and less than) `c[7]` than `v[8] = 0.099`. I'm very confused.

Comment: @Winston Ok, I've added a potential and short solution that reproduces your expected outcome. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can be more than one value that suits the criteria (i.e. more than one element in `v` which is lower than the positive values in `c`

```
positiveMatches <- which(c > 0) #Find the positive values in c

resultList <- list() #Set up a vector to store our data frames

#Loop through each positive match
for(i in positiveMatches){

    elementName <- paste0(i, "_", c[i]) #Name the list element after the index and value in c

    restrictedV <- c(rep(FALSE, i-1), rep(TRUE, length(v)-(i-1)))
    lowerMatches <- (v[i:length(v)] < c[i]) & restrictedV #Find the index of those elements in v which are less than our positive match in c
    resultList[[elementName]] <- data.frame(index = which(lowerMatches),
                                            value = v[lowerMatches]
                                            )
}
```

This should give you a list of dataframes, where each element is named after the index and value in c, and the dataframe contains 1 row per suitable element in v, providing the index and value of each element in v which was lower than the one in c.

[image]

The only tricks here were to work out the indexes where our values were true. I did that with the `which` command to get the indexes in c. Once I have those values, I could just loop through them, and work out the indexes which worked for each c in v, I did this with `lowerMatches <- v < c[i]`. Once I had all the information I just had to bind it together into a dataframe.

You didn't give an example of what you'd hope the output would be like so I came up with something I thought would be nice. You might want to modify this code to store the index and value of c as something other than the name of a list element, though.

You can get these back by using `names(resultList)` but at that point you should probably just try modifying the code to store those values somewhere more useful.

**EDIT:** I realised I missed the "from this point downwards" part, so I added an extra check in `restrictedV` that just generates an index of all the values that are allowed. If you don't want it to include the same row as in c (i.e. ignore index 5) just change the `i-1` to `i` in the `restrictedV` check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about the logic, but this reproduces your expected outcome and is short (base R only).

```
sapply(seq_along(c), function(i) {
    idx <- which(v < c[i]);
    if (length(idx) > 0) return(min(idx[idx > i])) else return(NA);
})
#[1] NA NA NA  5 NA NA  8 NA
```

---

### Sample data

```
c <- c(0,0,0,0.0927,0,0,0.100821,0)
v <- c(0.091,0.0981,0.101,0.102,0.092,0.1,0.091,0.099)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want it to? This method defines a custom function to apply to each row of the data, and then uses `purrr::pmap` to apply the function to each row and make a vector. You can then bind the vector as a new column to your data. This avoids `for` loops, though whether that is worth it is questionable. The result is a new column with `NA` if `c` is not positive, the row index of the later minimum if it is smaller than `v`, and `0` if it isn't.

Your given example doesn't have two cases that might show up. Every time `c` is positive here, `v` is larger than some later value, so `0` is never returned here. Also, there can be identical values in `v`, which makes the definition of "index of the minimum" ambiguous. Might be a simpler way to do this as well.

EDIT: I see the example data changed and you are actually looking for the first lower value, not the minimum value. Will try get back to this and fix it if you don't adapt this answer first!

```r
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)
v <- c(0.09199,0.0981,0.101,0.10002,0.0927273,0.1,0.091,0.099,0.105,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.100821,0.09)
c <- c(0,0,0,0,0.0927273,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.100821,0)

tbl <- tibble(c, v) %>% rowid_to_column()

is_v_lower <- function(rowid, c, v){
  if (c <= 0){
    return(NA)
  } else if (v > min(tbl$v[(rowid + 1):nrow(tbl)])) {
    min_index = which.min(tbl$v[(rowid + 1):nrow(tbl)])
    later_rowid = tbl$rowid[(rowid + 1):nrow(tbl)]
    return(later_rowid[min_index])
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}

output <- pmap_chr(tbl, is_v_lower)

new_tbl <- bind_cols(tbl, lower_v_index = output) %>% print()
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    rowid      c      v lower_v_index
#>    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>        
#>  1     1 0      0.0920 <NA>         
#>  2     2 0      0.0981 <NA>         
#>  3     3 0      0.101  <NA>         
#>  4     4 0      0.100  <NA>         
#>  5     5 0.0927 0.0927 15           
#>  6     6 0      0.100  <NA>         
#>  7     7 0      0.0910 <NA>         
#>  8     8 0      0.0990 <NA>         
#>  9     9 0      0.105  <NA>         
#> 10    10 0      0.100  <NA>         
#> 11    11 0      0.100  <NA>         
#> 12    12 0      0.100  <NA>         
#> 13    13 0      0.100  <NA>         
#> 14    14 0.101  0.101  15           
#> 15    15 0      0.0900 <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "tidyverse" to define tibbles (data.frames) and the `%>%` operator (pipe; see `?"%>%"` in the magrittr package).

```
library(tidyverse)
```

For any group and vectors x and y, I think your criterion is (adjust as necessary...)

```
f = function(x, y) { y[1] = x[1]; which.max(y < y[1]) }
```

Create a tibble from your original data, with a row index column `i`. Group the rows based on occurrences of non-zero values of `c`

```
tbl = tibble(i = seq_along(c), c, v) %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(c != 0))
```

Summarize the tbl, extracting the relevant information in each group

```
ans = summarize(tbl, i = i[1], idx = i[1] + f(c, v) - 1L)
```

Join the original table to the answer and clean up

```
> left_join(tbl, ans) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-i, -grp)
Joining, by = c("i", "grp")
# A tibble: 8 x 3
       c      v   idx
   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1 0      0.0910     1
2 0      0.0981    NA
3 0      0.101     NA
4 0.0927 0.102      5
5 0      0.0920    NA
6 0      0.100     NA
7 0.101  0.0910     8
8 0      0.0990    NA
```

Maybe place more of the logic in `f()`, e.g.,

```
f = function(i, x, y) {
    if (i[1] == 1L)
        return(NA)
    y[1] = x[1]
    i[1] + which.max(y < y[1]) - 1L
}
ans = summarize(tbl, i = i[1], idx = f(i, c, v))
left_join(tbl, ans) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-i, -grp)
```

This will help when, e.g., trying to decide the outcome when no values in v are less than c.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I'm working through the answers. Martin, can you explain "%>%"? I've searched for clarification but it's not something which easily yields search results.

Comment: It’s the pipe operator from `magrittr`.